# Use Table Valued Function for EF6 support of temporal queries?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, azure-sql-database, temporal-database

[This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859577) describes how to use TVFs with EF6 Database First so they can be used in Linq Queries like an entity for a SQL table.

It would seem possible to create a TVF that would query historical data from a SQL temporal table, and then have that available to Linq queries.

So for example the TVF might have code like this to get its resultset

```
    select c.Name, c.Age, c.Height, c.Weight from Child c FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF '2014-01-01'
```

The only problem I see is having to remap the TVF every time anyone regenerates the EDMX.

Is there a way to use T4 to automate mapping the TVF to the Child table?

Comment: Have a look at EF Reverse POCO to avid EDMX (and enable function mapping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Have a look at EF Reverse POCO to avid EDMX (and enable function
>   mapping) – ErikEJ Jan 24 at 7:36

Thank you for your answer Erik EJ.  I have had a great experience with Simon Hughes' VS Add-in.  We had been using EDMX solely to generate a model of the database tables.  EF Reverse POCO performs that task with beautiful efficiency, and supports TVF's too for temporal querying.